# I want to prove an events boolean algebra property. Is correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

$C$ has a Boolean algebra structure if and only if:

1. $Ω ∈ C$
2. If $ A ∈ C ⇒ A^c ∈ C$
3. If $A, B ∈ C ⇒ A ∪ B ∈ C$

**I want to prove that $0∈C$**

1. $Ω ∈ C$
2. If $ Ω ∈ C ⇒ Ω^c ∈ C$

$Ω^c=0 ⇒ 0∈C$

**Is correct?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $0$ is indeed defined as $\Omega^C$, then yes, that is correct.